# Ways to fetch the CPU percentage via PHP

Tags: php, shell, server

I've been searching weeks for a way to show up the percentage of CPU is getting used by the account on the server (not the whole server) so that the specific account can understand if they are overloading the server. So after a lot of Google search I finally find out this code:

```
<?php
    exec('ps -aux', $processes);
    foreach($processes as $process)
    {
        $cols = split(' ', ereg_replace(' +', ' ', $process));
        if (strpos($cols[2], '.') > -1)
        {
            $cpuUsage += floatval($cols[2]);
        }
    }
    print($cpuUsage);
?>
```

Which seems giving the right result but it is throwing `PHP Depricated Error` for `split()` & `ereg_replace()`.

So, I was wondering if any of you guys can take a look at it and let me know :

1. If this is the proper way to get the accurate cpu usage percentage for the user.
2. What should I do with the depricated functions?

P.S. I'm using it on PHP v7.0 RC3

Looking forward to answers.

Comment: The way you use doesn't make any sense as you are trying to sum up "pears" with "birds", expecting to get "tomatoes". Read this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58541

Comment: `top -b -n2 | grep "Cpu(s)"|tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2 + $4}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 'ps' command is the proper command in linux to get cpu usage.
2. In this case you may safely use preg_replace function instead of ereg_replace,  and explode instead of split.

   $cols = explode(' ', preg_replace(' +', ' ', $process));